# $\vec{x}\times\vec{y}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ and $\vec{x}\times\vec{a}=\vec{y}\times\vec{b}$, prove that $\vec{x}-\vec{b}\parallel\vec{y}-\vec{a}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How to prove that $\vec{x}-\vec{b}\parallel\vec{y}-\vec{a}$, knowing $\vec{x}\times\vec{y}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ and $\vec{x}\times\vec{a}=\vec{y}\times\vec{b}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute
\begin{align}
(\vec{x}-\vec{b})\times (\vec{y}-\vec{a})
\end{align}
directly and show it equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

Their cross-product is the zero vector:
$$(\vec{x}-\vec{b})\times(\vec{y}-\vec{a})=\vec{x}\times \vec{y}-\vec{x} \times \vec{a} - \vec{b} \times {y} + \vec{b} \times \vec{a}=(\vec{x} \times \vec{y} - \vec{a} \times \vec{b})+(\vec{x} \times \vec{a}-\vec{y} \times \vec{b})=\vec{0}$$
Where I used that $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{b} \times \vec{a} = \vec{0}$